# How to group records in Ecto and return them as a map?

Tags: sql, postgresql, elixir, ecto

I have `"influencer_platforms"` table in my DB which consists of:

```
id | influencer_handle | name
```

I want to query them and group by name like:

```
%{
  name1: [%{id: 1, influencer_handle: "i1"}, %{id: 3, influencer_handle: "i2"}],
  name2: [%{id: 2, influencer_handle: "i3"}]
}
```

How do do that in `Ecto`? So far I have:

```
defmacrop influencer_platform_json(influencer) do
  quote do
    fragment(
      "jsonb_agg(?)",
      fragment(
        "json_build_object(?, ?, ?, ?)",
        "id",                unquote(influencer).id,
        "influencer_handle", unquote(influencer).influencer_handle
      )
    )
  end
end

def all do
  from ip in InfluencerPlatform,
    group_by: :name,
    select: %{
      ip.name => influencer_platform_json(ip)
    }
end
```

Is is a more elegant way to achieve it?

Comment: Maybe use `bind_quoted` to avoid unquoting the `influencer` multiple times?

Comment: @MikeBuhot I'm not sure if that's work in `fragment`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want all this to be done in the database, you could collapse the two fragments into one. You also don't need to pass the column names as arguments to `fragment` if they're simple constants; you can put the column names inside the query in `fragment`.

```
defmacrop influencer_platform_json(influencer) do
  quote do
    fragment("jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('id', ?, 'influencer_handle', ?))", unquote(influencer).id, unquote(influencer).influencer_handle)
  end
end
```

---

You could also fetch the necessary data and do the group by in Elixir using `Enum.group_by/2`. This would be much more elegant but may be less performant than the above, depending on how optimized PostgreSQL's JSON handling is for the above query.

```
from(ip in InfluencerPlatform, select: map(ip, [:id, :name, :influencer_handle]))
|> Repo.all
|> Enum.group_by(fn ip -> ip.name end)
# Delete `:name` from each map.
|> Enum.map(fn {k, v} ->
  {k, Enum.map(v, &Map.delete(&1, :name))}
end)
|> Map.new
```